# Is there a clean way to setup websocket with symfony 2.6

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony, websocket

I developed a website using symfony 2.
Until now it was not using ajax. When you were posting a new comment the page was refreshed.

I added an ajax layer so the forms are submitted without refresh.

Everytime i publish a new post i want that all users online allowed to see this post receive it in their timeline.

This is what i did for now :

I created an event NewPostAdded and a subscriber rendering to html the post (in the hope i will send it to the client and the client will $('.timeline').prepend(post) )

I am looking for a way to implement a symfony2 command that will launch a websocket server. My subscriber will be able to push the post+datas(is it public ? else list of id of users allowed to see it) to this server. This server would then have a list of online users and if the post is public it will push to everybody else it will push it to the right online users.

i have done that before using symfony 2.1 + redis + nodejs + socket.io but it's obviously unmaintainable and since this website is not aimed to big audience i would like to keep things simple.

Here are my 2 question :

- Is there a bundle making think simple providing a all in one simple way to code a server with income events listeners (to receive posts from symfony) and event sender (to dispatch posts to the users), add event listeners client side (ready to use assets to add to be able to code client side) to react to server messages ?
- Is there a way to use something else than user id on client side to 'authenticate' the user on the websocket server to avoid users from changing the id in there client code to receive posts they are not supposed to view ?

Comment: look into eventsource (sse), it's a lot easier to use from "bare" php than sockets and can push out at any time using the same basic routine as http does. it's cant receive, but because of that limit, it's dead-simple to implement, and you can send from the client at any time anyway using ajax...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use php web socket Ratchet "http://socketo.me/", you can use it as composer package https://packagist.org/packages/cboden/ratchet

You should to create a service application, then you should to create a console command that will run the socket application.

Instead of userId you should generate a secret token like md5 hash of userId + some secret key that will be used to check is socket connection is trusted.

**Update:**

composer.json

```
...
"cboden/ratchet": "0.3.*",
...
```

Then you should to create a new bundle, lets say "WebSocketBundle"

1. Create a service application
   WebSocketBundle/WebSocket/WebSocketApplication.php

```
    namespace MyApp\WebSocketBundle\WebSocket;

    use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
    use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;

    class WebSocketApplication implements MessageComponentInterface
    {
        protected $container;
        protected $clients;
        protected $redis;

        public function __construct($container)
        {
            $this->clients = [];
            $this->container = $container;
            $this->redis = $container->get('snc_redis.something'); // your redis service
        }

        public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg)
        {
            $messageData = $this->decodeJSONAndCheckMessage($from, $msg);

            // here you must pass a token in messageData and implement own function to check is the token valid 
            $loginResult = $this->userLogin($from, $messageData);

            if ($loginResult instanceof Success) { // my custom success class message
                $this->handleMessage($from, $messageData);
            } else {
                $this->onError($from, new \Exception('Cannot login a user.'));
            }
        }

        // some strategy wrapper
        private function handleMessage($from, $messageData)
        {
            $message = $messageData->message;
            if (method_exists($this, $message)) {
                try {
                    $this->$message($from, $messageData);
                } catch (Exception $ex) {
                    $this->onError($from, $ex);
                }
            } else {
                $this->onError($from, new \Exception(sprintf('Unknown method "%s"', $message)));
            }
        }

        // you can use here post new message action
        private function eventStartSomething($from, $messageData)
        {
            if (!$messageData->somethingId) {
                $this->onError($from, new \Exception('Bad parameters'));
                return;
            }
            $scope = [];
            $scope['clients'][$from->resourceId] = null;

            // I need socket for something only limited amount of time, you can implement here own logic
            $this->redis->setex($messageData->somethingId, 600, serialize($scope));

            $this->clients[$from->resourceId]['scope'] = $messageData->eventId;
            $this->logMessage($from, 'started new something with Id: ' . $messageData->somethingId);
            $from->send($this->getResultOKMessage());
        }

        private function eventGetSomething($from, $messageData)
        {
            $scopeKey = $this->redis->get($messageData->somethingId);
            if (!$scopeKey) {
                $this->onError($from, new \Exception('Bad or expired something ' . $messageData->somethingId));
                return;
            }
            if (!$this->checkForClientInScope($from->resourceId, $messageData->eventId)) {
                if ($this->assignClientToScope($from->resourceId, $messageData->eventId)) {
                    $this->sendMessageToScope($from, $messageData->eventId, $this->getScopeWatchMessage($from, $messageData->eventId));
                    $from->send($this->getScopeWatchMessage($from, $messageData->eventId));
                }
            }
        }

        private function assignClientToScope($clienResourseId, $scopeId)
        {
            $result = false;
            $scopeKey = $this->redis->get($scopeId);
            if (!$scopeKey) {
                return $result;
            }
            $scope = unserialize($scopeKey);
            if (!array_key_exists($clienResourseId, $scope['clients'])) {

            // I need socket for something only limited amount of time, you can implement here own logic
                $this->redis->setex($scopeId, 600, serialize($scope));

                if (array_key_exists($clienResourseId, $this->clients)) {
                    $this->clients[$clienResourseId]['scope'] = $scopeId;
                }
                $result = true;
            }
            return $result;
        }

        private function sendMessageToScope($from, $scopeId, $message)
        {
            $scopeKey = $this->redis->get($scopeId);
            if (!$scopeKey) {
                $this->onError($from, new \Exception('Bad or expired event ' . $scopeId . ' for sending message'));
                return;
            }
            $scope = unserialize($scopeKey);

            foreach ($scope['clients'] as $clientResourceId => $remoteAddress) {
                if (array_key_exists($clientResourceId, $this->clients) &&
                        $this->clients[$clientResourceId]['connection'] != $from) {
                    $this->clients[$clientResourceId]['connection']->send($message);
                }
            }
        }

        public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn)
        {
            if (isset($this->clients[$conn->resourceId]['scope'])) {
                $scopeId = $this->clients[$conn->resourceId]['scope'];
                $this->removeClientFromScope($conn->resourceId);
                $this->sendMessageToScope($conn, $scopeId, $this->getScopeWatchMessage($conn, $scopeId));
            }
            unset($this->clients[$conn->resourceId]);
            $this->logMessage($conn, 'Connection closed.');
        }

        public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e)
        {
            echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . ":" . "WebSocket error::" . $e->getMessage() . " resourceId:" . $conn->resourceId . ". remoteAddress:" . $conn->remoteAddress . "\n";
            $conn->send($this->getErrorMessage($e->getMessage()));
        }

        public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
        {
            $this->clients[$conn->resourceId]['connection'] = $conn;
            $this->logMessage($conn, 'New connection.');
        }
    }
```

2. Console command:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use Snc\RedisBundle\Session\Storage\Handler\RedisSessionHandler;
use Ratchet\Session\SessionProvider;
use MyApp\WebSocketBundle\WebSocket\WebSocketApplication;

class ListenCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('myapp:websocket:listen')
            ->setDescription('Listen for websocket requests ')
            ->addOption('port', 'p', InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'The port to listen on', 8000)
            ->addOption('interface', 'i', InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'The interface to listen on', '0.0.0.0');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $redis = $this->getContainer()->get('snc_redis.default');
        $application = new WebSocketApplication($this->getContainer());
        $server = IoServer::factory(
            new HttpServer(
                new WsServer(
                    new SessionProvider(
                        $application,
                        new RedisSessionHandler($redis)
                    )
                )
            ),
            $input->getOption('port'),
            $input->getOption('interface')
        );
        echo "Listening on: ".$input->getOption('interface').":".$input->getOption('port')."\n";
        $server->run();

    }
}
```

Comment: So i can use this package in symfony2 by adding it to my composer.json ?

Comment: Do you have any example of implemetation of this in symfony2 ?

Comment: Yes, but can't post here full code case NDA,but will try to show you some key points

Comment: Excellent, i am going to try this right now ! Thank you for your help